# Find f'(c) and f'(0) s.t. f (x) < f (c) = f (0)

Tags: calculus

Let f be differentiable on $[0,1]$. If $c \in (0,1)$ s.t $f(x) \lt f (c)=f (0)$ for all $x  \in (0,1], x \ne c$, then what can be said about $f'(c) $ and $f'(0) $?

My attempt:

By definition of maxima, $f'(c)$ should be zero since $c$ seems to be given local maxima. But $f'(0)$ is tricky. Because for some point  $t \in (0, c)$ there should occur local maxima, this implies sign of $f'(x)$ in $[0, c)$ should be negative. Does this mean $f'(0) \lt 0$ or $f'(0) \le 0$, or neither?

Comment: totally unclear !

Comment: Whats not clear? The question asks for whether f '(x) is less than,greater than or equall to zero at x=c,0

Comment: Your attempt is good.  While $f'(c)$ is necessarily zero (since it is an interior critical point/local maximum), the information about $f'(0)$ is not so decisive, since $x=0$ is an endpoint of $[0,1]$.  Perhaps thinking about examples will finish your final thought.

Comment: Its an objective question I need to choose from given answers

Answer (score 0):

You are right that $f'(c)$ is zero, since $f$ has a local maximum at $c$, $f'(c)$ is defined, and $c$ is not an endpoint of the domain.

There is also a local maximum at $0$. If $f'(0)$ were positive, $f$ would be increasing at $0$ and so $f$ would be larger just to the right of $0$. That cannot be so, therefore $f'(0)$ is not positive. By the hypotheses $f'(0)$ is defined. Therefore, we have

> $$f'(0)\le 0$$

We cannot say more than that. For an example where $f'(0)<0$, see $f(x)=-16x^3+8x^2-x$ and $c=\frac 14$.

[image: Negative derivative at zero]

For an example where $f'(0)=0$, see $f(x)=cos(8x)-1$ and $c=\frac\pi{4}$.

[image: Zero derivative at zero]

(Sorry about the unequal sizes for the graphics: I'm not sure why that is happening.)